# ffmpeg screen recording using selection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, screen-recording

I use `ffmpeg` to record video from screen. I know that there are options to set size and offsets. I use this command:

```bash
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :1+100,200 output.mp4
```

where `1024x768` is size and `+100,200` are `x` and `y` offsets.

I want to find a way to use screen selection to set those size and offsets parameters. See below what I mean under the 'selection':

[image]

Is there a way to do this via `ffmpeg` itself or via some other native options?

PS. I have answered my own question below, but I use `flameshot` and it is not the solution out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is based on `flameshot` screen capture tool (image-only). It has `print-geometry` option:

> -g, --print-geometry          Print geometry of the
> selection in the format W H X Y.

So you can get size and offset from the output:

```bash
$ flameshot gui -g
838x394+590+361
```

---

### Solution itself

Install `flameshot`:

```bash
sudo apt install flameshot
```

Create script:

```bash
nano record_screen.sh
```

Content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
homedir=$( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f6 )
dir="$homedir/Videos/screen records"
params=$(flameshot gui -g)
array=(`echo $params | sed 's/+/\n/g'`)
now=`date "+%F_%H-%M-%S"`
filename="${dir}/${now}.mp4"
ffmpeg -video_size "${array[0]}" -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :1+"${array[1]}","${array[2]}" "${filename}"
```

Run:

```bash
bash record_screen.sh
```

It will ask you to select area:

[image]

And then will start recording

[image]

**You can stop the recording with `q` hotkey.**

Result will be placed to:
`~/Videos/screen records/`

---

### Open file

Also you can add this command to script into the end if you want to open directory with video file:

```bash
xdg-open "${dir}"
```

Or open file itself:

```bash
xdg-open "${filename}"
```